# Formulario con Bootstrap Select

Tags: css, bootstrap, adminlte, dropdown

Tengo un formulario con el siguiente código:

```
<form action="" name="formulario" id="formulario" method="POST">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <label for="">Tipo usuario(*):</label>
       <select name="idtipousuario" id="idtipousuario" class="form-control selectpicker" required>
       </select>
    </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

El problema es que se muestra doble, con dropdown antes del Select, estoy convencido que es alguna carga del CSS de Select que en teoría anula el dropdown pero lo he probado todo y ya no sé por donde tirar, estoy trabajando con adminLTE. ¿Se os ocurre algo?

[image: Formulario]

Comment: ¿Si le quitas la clase `selectpicker` tambien te lo hace?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes agregar tu CSS? Si copio y pego tu código en un jsfiddle no reproduce el problema. Por cierto en bootstrap la clase para el select es `form-select` tu pusiste `form-control` (La clase control normalmente se usa para `input`) Tal vez en tu CSS pusiste algo en `selectpicker` que sobre escribe los parámetros de la clase de bootstrap

Comment: ¿Que versión de bootstrap estas usando?  Segun parece adminLTE usa la versión 4.

Comment: @masterguru, si, he probado a quitar la clase y sigue igual, adminLTE viene con la versión 4 pero he probado a implementar la 5 con el mismo resultado

Comment: @HeytalePazguato en este momento estoy revisando el CSS, efectivamente, creo que como tú dices, por alguna parte estoy sobrescribiendo la clase Bootstrap porque si hago una inspección en el navegador me sale la clase .dropdown que en teoría el CSS de Bootstrap ya se encarga de borrrar...

Comment: @TaM, copiando y pegando tu código, cambio `form-control` por `form-select` y utilizando únicamente el `CSS` de Bootstrap me muestra el select de forma correcta

Comment: @TaM si has sido capaz de inspeccionar el select, comprueba si te sale repetido dos veces el elemento select (porque visualmente se aprecian dos) y con que clases, porque en ese caso estariamos ante otro problema que no seria el del CSS en si, sino otra cosa por descubrir aun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a todos por las sugerencias, al final lo he solventado importando los CDN del CSS y de JS de la versión de Bootstrap 4.6.1 y sustituyéndolos por los que trae adminlte. Me falta hacer algún retoque en el desplegable pero ya se visualiza correctamente y el propio CSS de Bootstrap anula el dropdown duplicado que me salía...

[image: Formulario Bootstrap Select]